# Mysql SELECT multiple users key if id exsist in the row

Tags: mysql

I would like to fetch all `users.myKey` from the table `committee` if the `id` is in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    myKey VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO users (name, myKey)
VALUES ("Gregor", "kx4ht"),
    ("Liza", "1lPxk"),
    ("Matt", "mP3fd"),
    ("Bob", "zStr5");
    
CREATE TABLE committee(
    user_id INT,
    friend_id INT,
    member_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `friend_id`, `member_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO committee (user_id, friend_id, member_id)
VALUES (4, 1, 3),
    (1, 2, 3);
```

What i got now:

```
SELECT u.myKey FROM users u INNER JOIN committee c ON (c.user_id = u.id || c.friend_id = u.id || c.member_id = u.id) WHERE u.id = 2 GROUP BY u.id;
```

Result now:
I get only my own `myKey` `user_id2`

What i expect:
I want only get the `myKeys` for the others inside `committee`. E.g if i `user 2` want get the `myKeys` from table `committee` where i can find my `user id 2`

In this case it should return the `myKey` for `user1 and user3`

Comment: That create schema/data script doesn't run in MySQL. Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, i copied wrong schema. I've updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to find a specific id in the "committee" table, find the id's that are *next to* the specified id and then find those neighboring ids in the "users" table and show their keys.

This is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT u.id, u.myKey
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT IF (tmp.user_id = 2, NULL, tmp.user_id) AS user_id,
                IF(tmp.friend_id = 2, NULL, tmp.friend_id) AS friend_id,
                IF(tmp.member_id = 2, NULL, tmp.member_id) AS member_id
            FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM committee
                    WHERE user_id = 2 OR friend_id = 2 OR member_id = 2) AS tmp) AS id_table
    ON u.id = id_table.user_id OR u.id = id_table.friend_id OR u.id = id_table.member_id
    WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL OR friend_id IS NOT NULL OR member_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that I am searching for the user with the id 2, as you specified.

The result of this query, as you said you would have expected it:

```
id | myKey
1 kx4ht
3 mP3fd
```

Comment: This is what i exactly looked for! Thank you!